# React-resolver for data Mock

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, resolver

I want to use `react-resolver` module to consume my data mock but i am not sure what i am doing wrong.

At the moment i have the following situation working fine

I have my data object:

```
const data = [
  {
    team: "TeamA",
    position: "dx",        
    active: "No",
  },
  {
    team: "TeamB",
    position: "dx",        
    active: "Yes",
  },
  {
    team: "TeamC",
    position: "sx",        
    active: "No",
  },
  {
    team: "TeamD",
    position: "dx",        
    active: "No",
  },
  {
    team: "TeamE",
    position: "dx",        
    active: "No",
  }
]
```

I can map it and render this data Object in the rows of my table component like `rows={renderRows(data)}`

Now i want to use `react-resolver`, i have create a Mock folder, i have put my data object.

This is how it looks now

```
import { resolver } from "../../path/of/my/resolver";

export const newDataResolver = resolver({

    const data = [
      {
        team: "TeamA",
        position: "dx",        
        active: "No",
      },
      {
        team: "TeamB",
        position: "dx",        
        active: "Yes",
      },
      {
        team: "TeamC",
        position: "sx",        
        active: "No",
      },
      {
        team: "TeamD",
        position: "dx",        
        active: "No",
      },
      {
        team: "TeamE",
        position: "dx",        
        active: "No",
      }
    ]

});
```

I am importing it now in my component like this

```
import { newDataResolver } from "../Mock"
```

How can i use now my `newDataResolver` object in my `renderRows` now that is imported from the mockup?

It is a very basic question but i am struggling. I would like now to do something like `rows={renderRows(newDataResolver)}`

Answer (score 0):

Try using decorator syntax:

```
import { resolve } from "react-resolver";

const data=[...]

@resolve("newData", function(props) {
  return data
})
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { newData } = this.props;

    return <SomeOtherComponent {renderRows(newData)} />
  }
}
```

This is the equivalent to asynchronously loading `newData` and providing it to the component as if it were provided directly:

```
<SomeComponent newData={newData} />
```

**EDIT**:
in order to achieve what you intended:

```
import { newDataResolver } from "../Mock"

 export default newDataResolver(SomeComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks it helps but it does not answer my question how i can import this new data resolved in my component?

Comment: ```
export default newDataResolver(SomeComponent)
```

Comment: Thanks if you can put it clear in your answer i can accept it